# phpseclib RSA Decryption with openssl

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, phpseclib

I used phpseclib for encryption, have some problem with openssl decrypt

```
//generate keys
extract($rsa->createKey(1024));
file_put_contents("public.pem",$publickey);
file_put_contents("private.pem",$privatekey);
```

encrypt text

```
    $rsa->loadKey($public_key); // public key
    $plaintext = '...';
    $ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
    file_put_contents("ciphertext.txt",$ciphertext);
```

So in linux i'm decrypting :

```
xxd -p ciphertext.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

And finally like the following command

openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem

get this error :

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190:
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:rsa_eay.c:674:
```

I am doing these settings for phpseclib :

```
define('CRYPT_RSA_PKCS15_COMPAT', true);
```

and now get this error on openssl:

```
error:04065084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data too large for modulus:rsa_eay.c:590:
```

public key :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDGCglgIcCG5a8xlZHEDRtQQTc4
kfxENNBtVN8bE4errA06mJ10WavP2Hg+k11NQip71IQPfIF9jlk1CsqT5ZHXOrOq
RmufHFLa3fiuPvFiMB1NjK4F28Gk4LwyZrfTWc2V6S0xpL5XkFeWRW6I69xckOXj
GqkC5dsWv/IlvPeVbwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

private key :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: phpseclib does OAEP padding (which is more secure) by default. Try doing `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`

Comment: set `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` but get this error : data too large for modulus:rsa_eay.c:590:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Few Comments.**

1. You may find this page helpful:

   http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html#rsaencpkcs1,p1phpseclib,p2openssl
2. I had suggested in my earlier answer that you do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`. Your latest edited post *still* does not have you doing that:

   ```
   $rsa->loadKey($public_key); // public key
   $plaintext = '...';
   $ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
   file_put_contents("ciphertext.txt",$ciphertext);
   ```

   Doing `define('CRYPT_RSA_PKCS15_COMPAT', true);` only does anything if you're in PKCS1 mode and you're not.
3. You're post says you're doing `openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem`. idk how the whole `xxd` command is supposed to work but normally, with OpenSSL, you need to specify an input file by doing `-in ciphertext.txt`, which you're not doing.

**Working Code**

Using your public and private key this worked for me:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$public_key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDGCglgIcCG5a8xlZHEDRtQQTc4
kfxENNBtVN8bE4errA06mJ10WavP2Hg+k11NQip71IQPfIF9jlk1CsqT5ZHXOrOq
RmufHFLa3fiuPvFiMB1NjK4F28Gk4LwyZrfTWc2V6S0xpL5XkFeWRW6I69xckOXj
GqkC5dsWv/IlvPeVbwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
$rsa->loadKey($public_key); // public key
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$plaintext = '...';
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
file_put_contents("ciphertext.txt",$ciphertext);
```

...and on the CLI:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem -in ciphertext.txt
```

Here's the output I got:

```
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, phpseclib does OAEP padding by default. It's more secure but less common. Try doing `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`.

Second, RSA does have an upper bound on the size of data that can be encrypted. For PKCS1 it's the size of the modulo - 11 (eg. `($rsa->getSize() >> 3) - 11`). idk how big the data you're trying to encrypt is but my guess is that it's bigger than that. So what phpseclib does in that situation is that it'll do `str_split` on it and then concatenate each of the successive ciphertext's. My guess is that that's what's happening in your case. So either you need to encrypt less data or come up with a different approach. eg. encrypt a symmetric key and then use the symmetric key to encrypt the data.

Comment: I just $plaintext = '...' encrypted,Another thing that happens when I'm set `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` retry with error : `RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:rsa_pk1.c:190: ` and when is it comment only `define('CRYPT_RSA_PKCS15_COMPAT', true);` get this error : `data too large for modulus:rsa_eay.c`

Comment: @lock - post a public / private key pair that reproduces the problem then. As is I can't reproduce the problem so any further posts on the subject without that would just be a waste of my time imho.

Comment: @lock - awesome - thanks! I'll try to take a look this evening - I'm about to head off to work!